# PHP exec() command can't open file

Tags: php, command

Why can't one of my PHP exec() commands open a file?

In my PHP script, there are three exec() commands, all of which can open files located in $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].  Two of the commands can also open files in the sub-directories (all directories and files have the same permissions), but one of the commands (**case "3"**) cannot.  I tested the 3 commands in terminal as the same Apache user, in the same sub-directories, and they all worked.  I also tested the script in the PHP CLI and they worked there as well.  Here is a snippet of the code:

```
switch($_POST['Convert']) 
    {
        case "1":
            $FileNameConvert .= ".pdf";
            $command = "convert '{$FileName}' '{$FileNameConvert}'";
            break;
        case "2":
            $FileNameConvert .= ".html";
            $command = "pdftohtml '{$FileName}' '{$FileNameConvert}'";
            break;
        case "3":
            $FileNameConvert = "RotatedPDF.pdf";
            $command = "pdftk '{$FileName}' cat 1-endsouth output '{$FileNameConvert}'";
            break;
        default:
            echo "error";
            exit();
    }
    echo exec($command,$op,$result);
```

Apache's error log shows:

```
I/O Error: Couldn't open file '$FileName': No such file or directory.
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
$FileName
```

Why does the following command not work?

```
$command = "pdftk '{$FileName}' cat 1-endsouth output '{$FileNameConvert}'";
```

Comment: Test the commands using PHP not just running the command as the apache user use the PHP cli from the terminal and see what the result is. `php -f  "yourfile.php"` you might have to change your file temporarily to execute without using the $_POST.

Comment: @PanamaJack: As advised, I tested the command using PHP CLI from the terminal and it worked in the terminal.

Comment: The third case is missing the dot for concatenating the file name ("$FileNameConvert =" vs " $FileNameConvert .=" for the other two). Could that be the issue?

Comment: @Faris: Yes!  Thank you for finding the needle in the haystack.